# How to store my data in Java?

Tags: java, datastore

I want save my program's data even program stop. But I dont want save basic txt file. while ı am search , ı just see database, sql etc But ı dont want web database. ı want save just my computer.

Comment: Save just my computer? Well, you're running out of ways to store data. What are you even trying to store?

Comment: You could use a Properties file, XML, local database (like h2)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I mean a computer which program running on it

Answer (score 0):

you can use a sqlite database in a file on the root directory of your code.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite/Connecting

Comment: The OP doesn't want sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a file to your home computer by specifying the path to your computer (i.e. "C:\Users..."). You can save the file in any format you want. What do you mean by "even program stop?"